# How to pre-pend and append a backslash for a vector in R

Tags: r, string

```
ids <- c("C1322", "C92348", "d2848", "19348")
```

I would like to prepend and append each element in `ids` so that the new string looks like the following:

`\'C1322\', \'C92348\', \'d2848\', \'19348\'`

I tried the following:

```
> paste0("\'", ids, "\'", collapse = ", ")
[1] "'C1322', 'C92348', 'd2848', '19348'"
```

But the backslash is not showing up.

Comment: That is not concatenating the backslash but rather the single quote

Comment: Yes. that's exactly my question. How can I concatenate the backslash

Comment: Why do you need the backslash? anyway you can do `cat(sprintf("\\'%s'\\", ids))`

Comment: @onyambu How can I add the comma in between the `ids`?

Comment: `cat(sprintf("\\'%s'\\", ids))` But I still do not understand why you need this. Note that this is just a printing issue

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need to string in such a format? Also be aware that when you print strings in the R console they are automatically escaped so what you see in the console may not be exactly what's in the string. When you `cat()` the value that will prevent any characters from being escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cat` with `paste0` like this:

```r
ids <- c("C1322", "C92348", "d2848", "19348")
cat(paste0("\\'", ids, "\\'", collapse = ", "))
#> \'C1322\', \'C92348\', \'d2848\', \'19348\'
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to store it as a string? instead of just printing it out?

Comment: @Adrian It already is a string, run `class(ids)` or `typeof(ids)` and see what the output is.

Comment: I'm referring to storing `cat(paste0("\\'", ids, "\\'", collapse = ", "))` as a string